# why is access denied to resources without jsessionid?

Tags: java, jboss, jsessionid

I've built an app that works great on my own local environment.  But when I deploy to our development environment which uses Siteminder for authentication, I get an "access denied" for all images and css files.  I noticed after authentication there'a a jsessionid appended to the url, so tested manually copying+pasting that jsessionid to the image url.  The image now shows!

Anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?  How come the jsessionid is important for access to images and css?

I'd be glad to post any code examples if that helps...

**Edit

I've turned on some extra logging and I see where the issue is, but not really how to solve it.

```
19:40:27,236 INFO  [STDOUT] 2010-12-17 19:40:27,236 [http-0.0.0.0-30080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException: SM_USER header not found in request.
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doAuthenticate(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:98)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:580)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

My Spring security settings:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

    <bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
        <property name="securityMetadataSource">
            <security:filter-security-metadata-source>
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/"
                    access="ROLE_VIEW_WELCOME" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/cfs"
                    access="ROLE_VIEW_WELCOME" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/app"
                    access="ROLE_VIEW_WELCOME" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome/**"
                    access="ROLE_VIEW_WELCOME" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/styles/**"
                    access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/scripts/**"
                    access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**"
                    access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/ruleManagement/**"
                    access="ROLE_VIEW_RULE_MANAGEMENT" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/vendorManagement/**"
                    access="ROLE_VENDOR_MANAGEMENT" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/userManagement/**"
                    access="ROLE_USER_MANAGEMENT" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/titleManagement/**"
                    access="ROLE_TITLE_MANAGEMENT" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/typeManagement/**"
                    access="ROLE_TYPE_MANAGEMENT" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/seriesManagement/**"
                    access="ROLE_SERIES_MANAGEMENT" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/sequenceManagement/**"
                    access="ROLE_SEQUENCE_MANAGEMENT" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/roleManagement/**"
                    access="ROLE_GROUP_MANAGEMENT" />                   
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/reports/**"
                    access="ROLE_REPORTS" />                                    
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/reportsNew/**"
                    access="ROLE_REPORTS" />                                        
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/fingerprint/**"
                    access="ROLE_FINGERPRINT" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
                    access="ROLE_VIEW_OTHER" />
            </security:filter-security-metadata-source>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="preauthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" />
        <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManagerParent" />

    <bean id="authenticationManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager"
        parent="authenticationManagerParent">
        <property name="providers">
            <list>
                <ref local="preauthAuthProvider" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="false" />
        <property name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.acegisecurity.concurrent.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <bean id="defaultConcurrentSessionController"
        class="org.acegisecurity.concurrent.ConcurrentSessionControllerImpl">
        <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/**"
                filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter, exceptionTranslationFilter, siteminderFilter, filterSecurityInterceptor" />
        </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
        <property name='securityContextRepository'>
            <bean
                class='org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository'>
                <property name='allowSessionCreation' value='true' />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="siteminderFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="principalRequestHeader" value="SM_USER" />
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="continueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication"
            value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mockSiteMinderFilter" class="com.disney.cfs.util.SiteMinderMockFilter"/>

    <bean id="preauthAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.disney.cfs.util.UserDetailsServiceUtil"/>

    <bean id="preauthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />

    <bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
        <property name="errorPage" value="/accessDenied.jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your browser settings. Probably your cookies are disabled. In this case the only way to identify session is passing it through the URL parameter.

Other possibility is a configuration of your authentication package (Siteminder). I personally do not know it but I guess that probably it requires passing the session ID through parameter and then compares it with the value it fetches from cookies. This is a way to make very secure applications that make hacker's life very hard. So, probably the better solution for you is to append the jsessionid to each url. You can do it easily if you are using custom tag libraries. In this case you can implement your own tag "a" that appends jsessionid to each value of href.

Comment: Thanks for the response...
Cookies are enabled on my browser.

I'll have to check with the team to see if you're right about Siteminder checking the jsessionid in url.